# How to simplify Kronecker delta with einstein summation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, cross-product, kronecker-delta

I am trying to proof a vector identity. I have to prove the following;
[image]

I am bit confused how to simplify the following part..
$$\delta_{il} \delta_{jm} x_{j}y_{l}z_{m}$$

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember Kronecker $\delta$ "is" the identity matrix, so contracting one suffix has the effect of replacing suffix.  So you get
$$\require{color}
{\color{blue}\delta_{il}}{\color{red}\delta_{jm}x_j}{\color{blue}y_l}z_m={\color{red}x_m}{\color{blue}y_i}z_m=y_i(x\cdot z).
$$

Comment: this is a very good intuitive explanation with colors. Thank you very much.